# How to add a double border-bottom to h2 using CSS?

Tags: css, markdown

I want to add this kind of border-bottom for h2 in CSS:

[image: The effect supposed to be]

I tried the following code in CSS:

```
 h2 {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: rgb(239, 112, 96);
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(239, 112, 96);
        padding-bottom: 5px;
  }

 h2::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(239, 112, 96);
        width: 25%;
        position: relative;
        bottom: -9px; /* your padding + border-width */
  }
```

and the following code in markdown:

```
## Statistics Programs
```

I got an almost perfect result. However, the thick bottom is not automatically equal to the length of h2 text.

[image: effect I got]

So, is it possible for me to **modify the CSS code alone** to get the ideal effect?

Comment: The length of the thick bottom is automatically equal to the length of h2 text.

Comment: No, you need updated html for this.

Comment: Thanks. I used markdown + CSS + markdown here. No HTML code was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
h2 {
  font-size:40px;
  display:inline;
  border-bottom:5px solid red;
}
h2::after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  border-top:3px solid red;
  margin-top:4px;
}
```

```html
<h2>A title here</h2>
<p> more text here</p>
```

Also like this:

```css
h2 {
  font-size:40px;
  display:inline;
  border-bottom:5px solid red;
}
h2 + hr {
  border-top:3px solid red;
  margin-top:4px;
}
```

```html
<h2>A title here</h2>
<hr>
<p> more text here</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's good. It works well in VS code, but not in Markdown here. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @hqgu what output you get with markdown? can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I guess that must be the problem of Markdown here chrome extension. This extension does not support use of ::after feature. Therefore, I only get the shorten bottom border.

Comment: @hqgu instead of the after, add an empty P element where you apply a border top and you should get the same result

Comment: @hqgu or you can use a hr element, I guess it's supported with markdown

Comment: thanks for your continuous support. Ther hr solution works well in markdown here chrome extension.  I used '---' in markdown after every "## title" elements.

Comment: @hqgu great, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue ;)

Comment: However, the "::after" still doesn't work well, even if I add an empty P element. The longer line still not showed. I don't know how to add a picture to  show it in the comments. Sorry about that.  Maybe I will add an hr element after every h2 element.

Comment: @hqgu for the empty P I was thinking the same as for the hr so without ::after but now the hr solution is better since it doesn't make a lot of sense to have an empty P for a simple border

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can achieve it:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Statistics Programs</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .container {
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(239, 112, 96);
   }
  .container h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgb(239, 112, 96);
    /* border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(239, 112, 96); */
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
   }

   .container h2::after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(239, 112, 96);
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     bottom: -5px; /*your padding + border-width */
   }
```

Link to the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpw8xr

Comment: Thanks very much. Your code works fine.  I'm wondering if it is possible for us to do this only with Markdown + CSS code?  I want to do it use markdown +css +markdown here.  I'm not sure markdown here knows how to use div tag and container attribute.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="child">
       Hello World
    </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```